# Quicksort-algorithm (java) does not sort at all

Tags: java, quicksort

I want to write a quicksort-algorith based on a pseudocode we were given. Everything is working fine, except that the algorithm does not sort the array at all, it just returns the same array.
Here is the algorith I used:

```
static void quickSort (double [] values, int low, int high)
    {
        if(low < high)
        {
            int p = partition(values, low, high);
            quickSort(values, low, p - 1);
            quickSort(values, p + 1, high);
        }
    }
```

```
static int partition(double [] values, int low, int high)
    {
        double pivot = values[high];
        int i = low - 1;
        for(int j = low; j < high; j++)
        {
            if(values[j] < pivot);
            {               
                i++;
                double tausch = values[i];
                values[i] = values[j];
                values[j] = tausch;
                //i++;
            }
        }
        double tausch = values[i + 1];
        values[i + 1] = values[high];
        values[high] = tausch;
        return i + 1;
    }
```

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        double [] values = {44, 67, 14, 15, 15, 11, 67, 17};
        for(int j = 0; j < values.length; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(values [j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
        quickSort(values, 0, values.length - 1);
        for(int j = 0; j < values.length; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(values [j] + " ");
        }
    }
```

I have no clue where the mistake might be, because an example I used works nearly identical but actuallly sorts the array.

Comment: At the end of your 5th line in your `partition` method, you have an extra semicolon at the end of the line: `if(values[j] < pivot);`.  Remove that semicolon, and your code should work!

Answer (score 1):

You have an error here.  Dangling semi colon.

```
   if(values[j] < pivot); // <-------------
```

Comment: That's not a syntax error, though it is a mistake.

Comment: Syntax error definition:  *a character or string incorrectly placed in a command or instruction that causes a failure in execution.*  The execution failed since it didn't sort.

Comment: In Java, a syntax error causes a failure at compile-time, not an incorrect behaviour at runtime. The extra semicolon here is syntactically correct, but logically wrong. The definition you quote is vague and I'm not sure where it comes from, but e.g. Wikipedia defines a syntax error as *"an error in the syntax of a sequence of characters or tokens that is intended to be written in compile-time. A program will not compile until all syntax errors are corrected"*.